# Ocaml lablgtk2 custom widget?

Tags: gtk, widget, ocaml

I've been learning Ocaml with lablgtk2 for a while and still searching for a tutorial in which describe a way to create a custom widget (I want to make this widget as a circle filled with color and some text in the center). And this custom widget can be set ~width, ~height, ~label, ~packing,... to another container (as another gtk widgets can).
unfortunately, I found no tutorial about this. I read how to make custom widget in gtk2+ and try to port into Lablgtk2 but still can't help.
Can anyone help me with this issue.
Really appreciate.

Comment: I asked about this to one of the co-maintainers of lablgtk2, and the answer is that what you want to do is not really convenient to do in lablgtk2 and you would be better of doing that part in C. Sorry.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq, this seems to be the only answer forthcoming to the question - perhaps you should repost it as an answer so the OP can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I hoped that someone would prove me wrong by answering this question, but here is what I wrote in a comment:

> I asked about this to one of the
>   co-maintainers of lablgtk2, and the
>   answer is that what you want to do is
>   not really convenient to do in
>   lablgtk2 and you would be better of
>   doing that part in C. Sorry.